# How can I get return with awaited along with return value

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have the following code give below. How can I give await with return value from GetAllGenres() method. Here is the code. I also given the code in launchsetting.js file. Is there any problem to call second  get method with parameter. It would work if I call 'api/testapi/2'

```
public class InMemoryRepository: IRepository
{
        private List<Genre> _genres;
        private readonly ILogger<InMemoryRepository> logger;

        public InMemoryRepository(ILogger<InMemoryRepository> logger)
        {
            _genres = new List<Genre>()
            {
                new Genre(){Id = 1, Name = "Comedy"},
                new Genre(){Id = 2, Name = "Action"}
            };
            this.logger = logger;
        }

        public async Task<List<Genre>> GetAllGenres()
        {
            return  _genres; // How can I add await return
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way:

```
async Task<IDetails> GetIDetailsAsync()
    {
        return await GetIDetailsAsync();
    }


async Task<Details> GetDetailsAsync()
{
    var details = await GetDetailsAsync();
    await details.InitializeAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this for return.

```
return await _genres;
```